# Reload 2 recyclerview in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment that has 2 `recyclerview` on right and left. How can I send data from the first `recyclerview` to the second `recyclerview` and update its data directly?

I made in activity as successful as the script below, but now I am confused what if in put in fragment.

[image]

The first `recyclerview` is the food menu list, the second `recyclerview` is the food menu that has been ordered.

the first `recyclerview` script "AdapterMenu", the script when clicking menu.

```
holder.llmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
    DataMenu menu = menuModels.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You clicked at position: " + (menu.getNama_menu()),      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(AddMenu)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
            Call<DataTambahValue> call = api.tambah(id,menu.getMenu_id());
            call.enqueue(new Callback<DataTambahValue>() {


                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<DataTambahValue> call, Response<DataTambahValue> response) {
                    String status = response.body().getStatus();
                    String message = response.body().getMessage();
                    if (status.equals("1")) {
                        // sukses, refresh data yang nampilin daftar pesanan.
                        Alerter.create(activity)
                                .setTitle("Informasi")
                                .setBackgroundColor(R.color.alerterSuccess)
                                .setText("Pesanan Ditambahkan ")
                                .show();
                        if (activity instanceof MainActivity){
                            MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) activity;
                            mainActivity.loadPesanan();
                        }

                        Log.w("Status",message);
                    } else {

                        Alerter.create(activity)
                                .setTitle("Informasi")
                                .setBackgroundColor(R.color.alerterError)
                                .setText("Jaringan Error")
                                .show();
                        // gagal.
                        Log.w("Status",message);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<DataTambahValue> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

        }
    });

}
```

script recyclerview second "AdapterMenuMesan", script when set the number of orders.

```
 holder.pemesananTambah.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {String idMenu = item.getPemesananId();
            Integer qty = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(holder.pemesananJumlah.getText()));
            qty++;
            // panggil retrofit untuk update qty nya.
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            //menyambungkan dengan webservice API edit
            API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
            Call<ResponseValue> call = api.edit("edit",idMenu, String.valueOf(qty));
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseValue>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseValue> call, Response<ResponseValue> response) {
                    String status = response.body().getStatus();
                    String message = response.body().getMessage();
                    if (status.equals("1")) {
                        // sukses, refresh data yang nampilin daftar pesanan.
                        Activity act = (Activity) activity;
                        if (act instanceof MainActivity) { // reload data pesanan
                            MainActivity main = (MainActivity) act;
                            main.loadPesanan();
                            Alerter.create(act)
                                    .setTitle("Informasi")
                                    .setBackgroundColor(R.color.alerterSuccess)
                                    .setText("Jumlah Pesanan " + item.getNama_menu() + " Ditambah")
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Activity act = (Activity) activity;
                        if (act instanceof MainActivity) { // reload data pesanan
                            MainActivity main = (MainActivity) act;
                            main.loadPesanan();
                            Alerter.create(act)
                                    .setTitle("Informasi")
                                    .setBackgroundColor(R.color.alerterError)
                                    .setText("Jumlah Pesanan " + item.getNama_menu() + " Gagal Ditambah ")
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseValue> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

        }
    });
    holder.pemesananKurang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {Integer qty = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf       (holder.pemesananJumlah.getText()));
            qty--;
            String idMenu = item.getPemesananId();
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            //menyambungkan dengan webservice API
            API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
            Call<ResponseValue> call = api.edit("edit",idMenu, String.valueOf(qty));
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseValue>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseValue> call, Response<ResponseValue> response) {

                    String status = response.body().getStatus();
                    String message = response.body().getMessage();
                    if (status.equals("1")) {
                        // sukses, refresh data yang nampilin daftar pesanan.
                        Activity act = (Activity) activity;
                        if (act instanceof MainActivity) { // reload data pesanan
                            MainActivity main = (MainActivity) act;
                            main.loadPesanan();
                            Alerter.create(act)
                                    .setTitle("Informasi")
                                    .setBackgroundColor(R.color.alerterSuccess)
                                    .setText("Jumlah Pesanan " + item.getNama_menu() + " Ditambah")
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Activity act = (Activity) activity;
                        if (act instanceof MainActivity) { // reload data pesanan
                            MainActivity main = (MainActivity) act;
                            main.loadPesanan();
                            Alerter.create(act)
                                    .setTitle("Informasi")
                                    .setBackgroundColor(R.color.alerterError)
                                    .setText("Jumlah Pesanan " + item.getNama_menu() + " Gagal Ditambah ")
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseValue> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

this method loadMenu () and load Order (). Script in fragment_1

```
public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment {

//private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager;
public AdapterMenu mAdapter;
public AdapterMenuPesanan mpAdapter;

private List<DataMenu> menuModels = new ArrayList<>();
private List<DataItem> itemModels = new ArrayList<>();

private Context context;
public static final String PREF = "ID";
public static final String URL ="http://192.168.99.98/webserviceKoffie/api/";

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@BindView(R.id.recyclerview_menu) RecyclerView recyclerView;
@BindView(R.id.recyclerview_pesanan) RecyclerView recyclerViewPesan;
@BindView(R.id.btnPesanMenu)  Button btnpesan;


@BindView(R.id.Total) Button Total;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_menu);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new AdapterMenu(menuModels,getActivity()));


    itemModels.clear();
    recyclerViewPesan = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_pesanan);
    recyclerViewPesan.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerViewPesan.setLayoutManager(layoutManager1);
    recyclerViewPesan.setAdapter(new AdapterMenuPesanan(itemModels,getActivity()));

    loadMenu();
    loadPesanan();
    return view;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void finish() {
}

public void loadMenu(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
    Call<DataMenuValue> call = api.menu();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<DataMenuValue>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DataMenuValue> call, Response<DataMenuValue> response) {
            String value = response.body().getStatus();
            menuModels = response.body().getData();
            if(value.equals("1")){
            mAdapter = new AdapterMenu(menuModels,getActivity());
                Log.d(String.valueOf(response.body().getData()), "onResponse: aaaa");
            staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(5,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            staggeredGridLayoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            SpaceItemDecorationView decoration = new SpaceItemDecorationView(getActivity(),5);
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DataMenuValue> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

public void loadPesanan(){
    SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREF, getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);

        final String id = pref.getString("id",null);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
        Call<DaftarPesananValue> call = api.daftarPesanan("getData",id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<DaftarPesananValue>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DaftarPesananValue> call, Response<DaftarPesananValue> response) {

                int value = response.body().getStatus();
                itemModels = response.body().getDatas();

                int harga = 0;
                for(int i=0; i<itemModels.size();i++){
                    harga += Integer.parseInt(itemModels.get(i).getTotalHarga());
                }

                Log.w("Total",String.valueOf(harga));

                Total.setText(String.valueOf(harga));
                if(value == 1){
                    mAdapter = new AdapterMenu(menuModels,getActivity());
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManagerPemesanan = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManagerPemesanan);
                    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                }
                else{
                    Total.setText("0");
                    mpAdapter = new AdapterMenuPesanan(itemModels, getActivity());
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManagerPemesanan = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManagerPemesanan);
                    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(mpAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DaftarPesananValue> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

I know the error in

```
Activity act = (Activity) activity;
                        if (act instanceof MainActivity) {// reload order data
                            MainActivity main = (MainActivity) act;
                            main.loadOrder ();
```

I am confused what to substitute MainActivity in the fragment, I already replace with fragment_1 but still error. What should I do ?

Comment: first add data to secondAdapter on click and then call secondAdapter.notify() method  to refresh recyclerview

Comment: You can also use interface to communicate between 2 adapters.